# Galaxy Nexus: Disable screen lock during call

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, lock-screens, calls

My GN Device locks the screen when I start a call.  Most of my calls are made using BT headset, and I don't need the lock in that scenario.

Is there a way to disable the automatic screen lock when a headset is used?

Comment: Is this still an issue on JB?

Comment: No, it isn't - I will answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved under Jelly Beans.